# Django smart_str on queryset

Tags: django, unicode, django-queryset

I need to use `smart_str` on the results of a query in my view to take care of latin characters. How can I convert each item in my queryset?

I have tried:

```
...
mylist = []
myquery_set = Locality.objects.all()
for item in myquery_set:
    mylist.append(smart_str(item))
...
```

But I get the error:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, <object> found
```

What is the best way to do this? Or can I take care of it in the template as I iterate the results?

**EDIT:** if I output the values to a template then all is good. However, I want to output the response as an .xls file using the code:

```
...
filename = "locality.xls"
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'
return response
```

The view works fine (gives me the file etc.) but the latin characters are not rendered properly.

Comment: Why? You're already dealing with unicode.

Comment: Sorry. My edit should make the problem clearer. Output to straight template is fine. The excel table has the problems. I am guessing maybe I need to do something more with response rather than the queryset?

Comment: If your view produces the .xls you could give pythons unicodecsv lib a try and generate a csv file which can be read by excel. https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Comment: Heh. If only life were that simple. I already have a view generating a .csv file ASWELL. The client has requested a native .xls formatted file as a download option. With that view I used smart_str to address the unicode errors, which is why I though it could be used for the excel view. The view code is quite different though.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're executing `smart_str` on Model object, instead of a string (so basically you're trying to convert object to string). The solution is to `smart_str` on a field:

```
mylist.append(smart_str(item.fieldname))
```